# is this higher-order function correct?

Tags: erlang

As part of learning Erlang, one of the problems I am trying to solve is

> Write a higher-order function filter(F, L), which returns all the
>   elements X in L for which F(X) is true.

I am new to functional programming and very confused with higher-order functions as well.

My attempt looks like

```
filter(F, L)  -> [T || T <- L, F(T) =:= true].

2> IsEven = fun(X) -> X rem 2 =:= 0 end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.90072148>
3> IsEven(2).
true
4> IsEven(3).
false
5> math_functions:filter(IsEven, lists:seq(1, 10)).
[2,4,6,8,10]
6> math_functions:filter(IsEven, lists:seq(1, 20)).
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

**Question**
Is this is really higher-order function? Please guide

Comment: filter takes one function as input, so it is a higher order function.

Comment: Your attempt looks good. A higher order function is just a function which either takes a function as input or returns a function as output.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pascal and LeoCorrea for reviewing the code